# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally using Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome through WebDriverManager

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-python

I'm running this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=chrome_options)

driver.get('http://192.168.15.1/me_configuracao_avancada.asp',)
user = driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtUser")
user.send_keys("support")
pass_ = driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtPass")
pass_.send_keys("password")
btnLogin = driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnLogin")
btnLogin.click()
driver.get('http://192.168.15.1/reboot.asp',)
reboot = driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnReboot")
reboot.click()
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
print("Modem Reiniciado!")
```

I'm using Google Chrome 103.0.5060.134, ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.134 and Selenium version 4.3.0.
But when I run the script, this error messages appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modem.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
  File "/home/fabio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/fabio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/fabio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/fabio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 370, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/fabio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/fabio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x56156ba81cd3 <unknown>
#1 0x56156b889968 <unknown>
#2 0x56156b8ae25c <unknown>
#3 0x56156b8a98fa <unknown>
#4 0x56156b8e494a <unknown>
#5 0x56156b8deaa3 <unknown>
#6 0x56156b8b43fa <unknown>
#7 0x56156b8b5555 <unknown>
#8 0x56156bac92bd <unknown>
#9 0x56156bacd418 <unknown>
#10 0x56156bab336e <unknown>
#11 0x56156bace078 <unknown>
#12 0x56156baa7bb0 <unknown>
#13 0x56156baead58 <unknown>
#14 0x56156baeaed8 <unknown>
#15 0x56156bb04cfd <unknown>
#16 0x7fbf96e7c609 <unknown>
```

Some weeks ago the script ran without any issues, but now it gives this error. How can I correct it?

Comment: Presuming you are executing as a non-root user, 1) can you remove the arguments `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-dev-shm-usage`. 2) Does your tests execute well in **non** `--headless` mode?

Comment: So i remove the arguments --no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage and --headless, but the error continues, i'm running the script on Ubuntu Server 20.4.3 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take care of a couple of things here as follows:

- You need `webdriver.Chrome()` only once. If you don't need the arguments through `Options()` keep:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
  ```

  and remove:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=chrome_options)
  ```

  or vice versa.
- If you are executing as a **non-root** using `add_argument('--headless')` generally you may not even require the following arguments:

  - *`add_argument('--no-sandbox')`*
  - *`add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')`*
- You can try to initiate the new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) using:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
  ```
- Your effective code block will be:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

  chrome_options = Options()
  chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
  # optional
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  # optional
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=chrome_options)
  driver.get('http://192.168.15.1/me_configuracao_avancada.asp')
  ```

> ***Note***: Ensure that you have installed [**webdriver-manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal) and [**Chrome**](https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/) browser within your system before you kickoff your test execution.